# How to make old message from the function in the button disappear and new one appear within the function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My problem is that everything that i tried did't work and made errors. So i'm looking for a way to add function to a button that would clear what was displayed and run other function again.

```
import tkinter
import random
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("D&D Stat Roller")
window.geometry("600x250")
start_label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Welcome to D&D Stat Roller").pack()
d6 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
how_to = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Rolled stats are determined by trowing a d6 4 times and 
subtracting the lowest number.").pack()
def roll_stats():
    def rollstat():
        global stat
        stat = []
        stat.append(random.choice(d6))
        for number in stat:
            if len(stat) < 4:
                stat.append(random.choice(d6))
            if len(stat) == 4:
                break
        low = min(stat)
        global stat1
        stat1 = sum(stat) - low
    stat_value = []
    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text = "First rolled stat: %s. Stat value: %s" % (stat, stat1)).pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Second rolled stat: %s. Stat value: %s" % (stat, stat1)).pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Third rolled stat: %s. Stat value: %s" % (stat, stat1)).pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Fourth rolled stat: %s. Stat value: %s" % (stat, stat1)).pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Fifth rolled stat: %s. Stat value: %s" % (stat, stat1)).pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Sixth rolled stat: %s. Stat value: %s" % (stat, stat1)).pack()

    value = sum(stat_value)
    tkinter.Label(window, text = "Your full stat value is %s/108" % value).pack()
tkinter.Button(window, text = "ROLL!", command = roll_stats).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Also if somebody knows how i could shrink the code even further (before it was at least twice as long) i would be more than interested to know how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried `config()` method? and f strings are there to make life easier for you, but choosing placeholders here, is making your code longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here im using `config()` method to update the label widgets. Firstly you will have to declare the Labels and assign a variable to it outside the function. Like:

```py
first = tkinter.Label(window) #recommended to use import tkinter as tk and then tk.Label(...)
second = tkinter.Label(window)
third = tkinter.Label(window)
fourth = tkinter.Label(window)
fifth = tkinter.Label(window)
sixth = tkinter.Label(window)
avg = tkinter.Label(window)
```

Then now, inside the function you can use `config` on this variables and `pack()` them, like:

```py
first.config(text=f"First rolled stat: {stat}. Stat value: {stat1}") #say this to all the widgets
first.pack()
```

I've replaced each placeholders with `f` strings as its more easier, and serves the same purpose here.

So here is your entire code, formatted more clearly.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("D&D Stat Roller")
window.geometry("600x250")

start_label = tk.Label(window, text="Welcome to D&D Stat Roller").pack()
d6 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
how_to = tk.Label(window, text="""Rolled stats are determined by trowing a d6 4 times and 
subtracting the lowest number.""")
how_to.pack()


def roll_stats():
    def rollstat():
        global stat
        stat = []
        stat.append(random.choice(d6))
        for number in stat:
            if len(stat) < 4:
                stat.append(random.choice(d6))
            if len(stat) == 4:
                break
        low = min(stat)
        global stat1
        stat1 = sum(stat) - low

    stat_value = []
    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    first.config(text=f"First rolled stat: {stat}. Stat value: {stat1}")
    first.pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    second.config(text=f"Second rolled stat: {stat}. Stat value: {stat1}")
    second.pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    third.config(text=f"Third rolled stat: {stat}. Stat value: {stat1}")
    third.pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    fourth.config(text=f"Fourth rolled stat: {stat}. Stat value: {stat1}")
    fourth.pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    fifth.config(text=f"Fifth rolled stat: {stat}. Stat value: {stat1}")
    fifth.pack()

    rollstat()
    stat_value.append(stat1)
    sixth.config(text=f"Sixth rolled stat: {stat}. Stat value: {stat1}")
    sixth.pack()

    value = sum(stat_value)
    avg.config(text=f"Your full stat value is {value}/108")
    avg.pack()


tk.Button(window, text="ROLL!", command=roll_stats).pack()

first = tk.Label(window)
second = tk.Label(window)
third = tk.Label(window)
fourth = tk.Label(window)
fifth = tk.Label(window)
sixth = tk.Label(window)
avg = tk.Label(window)


window.mainloop()
```

If any errors, do let me know.

Comment: Thank that was really helpful, and because i learn as i go and look for thing that work for me (destroy and delete didn't work, probably did it wrong), i was playing with config after you suggested but still had some problems with how to use them in this but thanks to you now i know what i did wrong. And i got to know f string which are cleaner in my opinion.